# How to keep with value along time?

Tags: c#, asp.net

> I have my task to check on the login user on operating system as I
>   collect some details about him as username
>
> I had my code well and it worked well .
>
> But my issue is to keep with the logged user through all pages without
>   checking with the logged user in each page .As I check on user at
>   Master page , also when I tought about session but session have timout
>   .

Master page

```
 private void checkUser()
{

        DirectorySearcher searcher = new DirectorySearcher();
        searcher.SearchScope = SearchScope.Subtree;
        searcher.Filter = string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,               "(sAMAccountName={0})", Environment.UserName);
        //SearchResult findUser = searcher.FindOne();
        foreach (SearchResult findUser in searcher.FindAll())
        {
            if (findUser != null)
            {
                DirectoryEntry user = findUser.GetDirectoryEntry();
                LoggedUser = user.Properties["displayName"].Value.ToString();
            }
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **[ASP.NET Session](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581.aspx)** to store data related to the logged in user and they will last until session expires. You can also manage session timeout duration as per your requirement.

If you set up **[Authentication](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eeyk640h%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)** and **[Authorisation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wce3kxhd.ASPX)**, you don't have to check if user is authorised or not for each page, system will do that for you. If session expired or user is unauthorised, system will redirect the request for the login page (if form authentication is used) or right credentials for authorisation.